# Convert String dates to Date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains dates as String like

```
1    Aug 10, 2018
2    Aug 13, 2018
3    Aug 9,  2018 
4    Jan 23, 2018
5    Aug 31, 2018
6    Jan 29, 2018
```

How can i get this to display as:

```
1   10/08/2018 #I'm european
2   13/08/2018
3   09/08/2018
4   23/01/2018
```

etc.

So that it become the date datatype instead of String.

Comment: Check out `?format.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lubdridate package in R

`install.packages("lubridate)`

`library(lubridate)`

`df$time <- format(mdy(df$time),"%d/%m/%Y)`

Assuming df$time is the column with the date string

Answer (score 1):

See this [helpful page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/) or `?strptime`.

```
format(as.Date("Aug 10, 2018", format = "%b %d, %y"), "%d/%m/%Y")
## [1] "10/08/2020"
```

Using the df from @Dirk:

```
df <- data.frame(v = 1:6, d = c("Aug 10, 2018", "Aug 13, 2018", "Aug 9,  2018", 
                                "Jan 23, 2018", "Aug 31, 2018", "Jan 29, 2018"))
df$newd <- format(as.Date(df$d, format = "%b %d, %y"), "%d/%m/%Y")
#   v            d       newd
# 1 1 Aug 10, 2018 10/08/2020
# 2 2 Aug 13, 2018 13/08/2020
# 3 3 Aug 9,  2018 09/08/2020
# 4 4 Jan 23, 2018 23/01/2020
# 5 5 Aug 31, 2018 31/08/2020
# 6 6 Jan 29, 2018 29/01/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this reproducible:

```
R> df <- data.frame(v=1:6, d=c("Aug 10, 2018", "Aug 13, 2018", "Aug 9,  2018", 
+                              "Jan 23, 2018", "Aug 31, 2018", "Jan 29, 2018"))
R> df
  v            d
1 1 Aug 10, 2018
2 2 Aug 13, 2018
3 3 Aug 9,  2018
4 4 Jan 23, 2018
5 5 Aug 31, 2018
6 6 Jan 29, 2018
R> library(anytime)              # parse dates and times without formats
R> df$date <- anydate(df$d)      # finds matching format
R> df
  v            d       date
1 1 Aug 10, 2018 2018-08-10
2 2 Aug 13, 2018 2018-08-13
3 3 Aug 9,  2018       <NA>
4 4 Jan 23, 2018 2018-01-23
5 5 Aug 31, 2018 2018-08-31
6 6 Jan 29, 2018 2018-01-29
R>
```

Row three is a known shortcoming of the underlying parser from the Boost library--it works once you write the date with two digits ie 'Aug 09, 2018'.

To get the output you want, you can either use `format()` or `strptime()` -- or stick with one of the *standardized* formats.  You already get ISO8601 by default, here we add another one (using another function from package `anytime`):

```
R> df$fmt <- rfc2822(df$date)
R> df
  v             d       date              fmt
1 1  Aug 10, 2018 2018-08-10 Fri, 10 Aug 2018
2 2  Aug 13, 2018 2018-08-13 Mon, 13 Aug 2018
3 3 Aug 09,  2018 2018-08-09 Thu, 09 Aug 2018
4 4  Jan 23, 2018 2018-01-23 Tue, 23 Jan 2018
5 5  Aug 31, 2018 2018-08-31 Fri, 31 Aug 2018
6 6  Jan 29, 2018 2018-01-29 Mon, 29 Jan 2018
R>
```

Lastly, I recommend against the format you desire because it can be misleading / misinterpreted but for completeness:

```
R> df$bad <- format(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
R> df
  v             d       date              fmt        bad
1 1  Aug 10, 2018 2018-08-10 Fri, 10 Aug 2018 10/08/2018
2 2  Aug 13, 2018 2018-08-13 Mon, 13 Aug 2018 13/08/2018
3 3 Aug 09,  2018 2018-08-09 Thu, 09 Aug 2018 09/08/2018
4 4  Jan 23, 2018 2018-01-23 Tue, 23 Jan 2018 23/01/2018
5 5  Aug 31, 2018 2018-08-31 Fri, 31 Aug 2018 31/08/2018
6 6  Jan 29, 2018 2018-01-29 Mon, 29 Jan 2018 29/01/2018
R>
```

The use of `/` as a separator *will* make people think it is the silly North American m/d/y order.  I suggested you at least replace `%m` with `%b`.

Comment: OP asked for the European formatting of date (dd/mm/yyyy) (which, annoyingly, is the one format anydate DOESN'T recognize, but that's beside the point). Your answer needs an additional `format` line that will display the dates as requested.

Comment: Good point, thank you.  Added.